# How to remove a YUI Chart from a page

Tags: javascript, yui, charts

I need to create and remove YUI charts from a page. To remove, I am doing `$('.chart').remove()` to get rid of the containing DIV. However, this raises a null reference exception in this script:

```
try {
document.getElementById("yuiswf1").SetReturnValue(__flash__toXML(YAHOO.widget.SWF.eventHandler("yuiswf1",
({category:"info",message:"resize (width: 0, height: 0)",type:"log"})
)) ); } 
catch (e) { 
document.getElementById("yuiswf1").SetReturnValue("<exception>" + e + "</exception>");     
}
```

I assume YUI attaches this code for some event handler which is failing since the DIV has been removed.

How can I remove a YUI chart without causing this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the destroy method on your chart object before removing its parent div.

mychart.destroy(); (assuming your variable for the chart is mychart)

If you still have issues, you can try posting back on yui library's forum. 
http://yuilibrary.com/forum/

Tripp